# Add a link to Language Learning Beta to "What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: support, status-completed, on-topic-off-topic

I think Language Learning Beta is relatively new and must not have existed when the ELL help page was created.

I suggest adding a link to [Language Learning Beta](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) to ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Here's the relevant section of that page:

> Please don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are
>   out of scope for this site:
>
> - Proofreading (for example, "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?"), unless a source of concern is clearly specified
> - Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup (these are off topic on ELL, and there are many free dictionaries available
>     online. If you are asking about the meaning of a word or phrase, you
>     should look up those words in a dictionary first. If you are still
>     confused, be sure to summarize what you found when you did your
>     initial research, and summarize that information in the question.)
> - "How can I improve my English?" or "What's a good tool for...?" (these are not constructive, because what works well for one learner
>     may not work so well for another)
> - Translation and non-English languages
> - Naming, including naming programming variables/classes
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature (you may ask about the meaning of a sentence or passage you find in literature,
>     but be sure you provide sufficient context and cite the source where
>     this material was found)
> - Requests for resources (we have a Resources List on Meta which you might find useful)

It's the third bullet where I think a link to Language Learning would fit especially well.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to add a bullet in the section where we recommend other sites for certain frequent off-topic question types we typically get on ELL:

> If you have questions about the following topics, you may want visit other Stack Exchange sites to see if they would be a better place to ask your question (but please do not post the same question on two difference Stack Exchange sites):
>
> - Etymology, evolution of the English language, or historical English –
>     you may get a more detailed answer at [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com)
> - Writing advice – see [writers.stackexchange.com](https://writers.stackexchange.com)
>     instead
> - Questions about language learning techniques and
>     their effectiveness - see [languagelearning.stackexchange.com](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com)

I don't think the "How can I improve my English? questions that we get on ELL are of the type that would be good for Language Learning, so I would rather come up with a really great bullet point for the "If you have questions about the following topics..." section.

Comment: Unrelated and minor, but the description of what’s appropriate to ask on ELU is a bit limited in scope: etymology, evolution, and history of English. That all sounds like it only boils down to “how English used to be”. We also welcome questions on contemporary English and even emerging slang not yet widely recorded in dictionaries. Plus orthography, morphology, syntax, some semantics and pragmatics, and other interesting aspects of English no matter what era.

Comment: @DanBron The text was written to divert common questions that we get on ELL that are better asked on EL&U. It's not really intended to be a comprehensive listing of what could be asked on EL&U, the same way that writing advice isn't the only thing on-topic on Writers.

Comment: @ColleenV I see! Makes sense, thank you.

Comment: The mod team has discussed it and we think it's a good idea to add the Language Learning bullet. We're also looking for a word to replace "detailed" in the EL&U bullet, because it doesn't really seem to capture the difference between the more pragmatic answers a poster is likely to get on ELL and the more (mumble) answers that EL&U provides. I think the difference in detail isn't as salient as the difference in focus. Any thoughts? @DanBron

Comment: Linguistic, grammatical, conceptual, academic...?

Comment: I thought about academic but the [definition for learners](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/academic) after "of or relating to schools and education" is "having no practical importance : not involving or relating to anything real or practical" and I don't think that's exactly the nuance we're looking for! Linguistic might work. @DanBron

Comment: @ColleenV "Linguistic" could be on the right track, but what is a "linguistic answer"? Maybe "more detailed answers to questions about linguistic theory," or something along those lines?